# What are run time inputs in python3?

Tags: python, android

I have been recently been trying out this app called compiler(on android) and whenever I try run code it is asking for something called a runtime input? I am new to coding so I really don't know what it means. Another issue is that when I try to run inputs e.g input("hi: ") I am unable, to type anything in the terminal, wondering if there is any fix? In advance thanks to anyone who responds.For some reasons the staic terminal does not apply to other ides such as pycharm or pydroid[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRwpC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue in the most of the online ide. You have to provide your input in that alert box and hit **run**.
The reason it happens is because your code is not running on your device instead running on a remote server which only allocates limited time(3-5 seconds) for your code to execute, so to make full use of that time, you are asked to give all the input beforehand so that program doesn't have to wait for user input and waste that precious time.
Also, you **can't** expect prompt messages to work here as they are working in an offline ide.